# Django - inline formset validation

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to validate my inline formset cost value's to make sure that it adds up to 100. The formset is returned 5 times so foreach the value should be added until 100 is hit. If it's more or less than that show an error & not allow the user to hit the create button. I'm trying to validated all the forms combined not each form value.

**Models.py**

```
class EstimatedBudgetForm(forms.ModelForm):
def clean(self):
    # get forms that actually have valid data
    count = 0
    for percentage in self.cost:
        try:
            if percentage.cleaned_data:
                count += percentage
        except AttributeError:
            # annoyingly, if a subform is invalid Django explicity raises
            # an AttributeError for cleaned_data
            pass
    if count != 100:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Percentage must equal 100%')
```

**Views.py**

```
EstimatedBudgetChildFormset = inlineformset_factory(
  Project, EstimatedBudget, fields=('project', 'item', 'cost', 'time'), can_delete=False, form=EstimatedBudgetForm, extra=5, widgets={'item': forms.Select(attrs={'disabled': True})},
)
```

Comment: You have mentioned what you want to do and what you tried, but you haven't mentioned the problem. Is it that this does not work as you expect (It won't because you are just validating each form individually)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes I am trying to validate all forms combined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform validation for a formset one should override the `clean` method of the formset (not the form). For an inline formset you need to inherit from `BaseInlineFormSet` and use that (For more information see [Overriding clean() on a ModelFormSet [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset)):

```
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet


class MyInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            if not form.errors: # No need for a try-except, just check if the form doesn't have errors
                count += form.cleaned_data['cost']
        if count != 100: # This condition might not work if you are dealing with floating point numbers
            raise forms.ValidationError('Percentage must equal 100%')
```

Next while making the formset, specify the `formset` kwarg rather than `form`:

```
EstimatedBudgetChildFormset = inlineformset_factory(
  Project, EstimatedBudget, fields=('project', 'item', 'cost', 'time'), can_delete=False, formset=MyInlineFormset, extra=5, widgets={'item': forms.Select(attrs={'disabled': True})},
)
```

Comment: If I were to loop down the formset rows and get **individual values to compare**, how do I do it? For example, if the value of field `cost` in the 1st row is say, 100, I assign it to a variable **x**. The iteration then moves to the next row and assign the value (which is 120) to **y**. Then compare the values of **x** with **y** and run a _check that the difference should not be more than 10%_. **PS** I need to run such comparison only for the two adjoining rows.